# Erro ao utilizar o POST AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular, post, get

Meu controller está assim:

```
app.controller("listaTelefonicaController", function ($scope, $http)
```

Dentro dele está minha função de adicionar

```
ctrl.adicionarContatos = function (contato) {
            contato.telefone = ctrl.formatCel(contato.telefone);
            console.log(contato);
            var data = JSON.stringify(contato);
            $http.post("/contatos.json", {cont: data},{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}).then(
                 function (response) {
                     console.log("success:" + response);
                     delete ctrl.contato;
                     $scope.contatoForm.$setPristine();
                     return response;
                 },
                 function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
                     return response;
                 }
             );

            // $http({
            //         url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/contatos.json',
            //         method: "POST",
            //         headers: {
            //             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            //             'Accept': 'application/json'
            //         },
            //         data: contato
            //     })
            //     .then(function (response) {
            //             console.log("success:" + response);
            //         },
            //         function (response) { // optional
            //             console.log("Fail:" + response.data);
            //         });
            };
```

Fiquei algumas horas procurando e testando de várias formas e todas apareciam o mesmo erro:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/contatos.json 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Esse arquivo está populado com alguns dados como esse abaixo:

```
{
    "nome": "Larissa",
    "telefone": "9999-3399",
    "cor": "orange",
    "data": "2015-04-12T12:53:46.204Z",
    "operadora": {
        "nome": "GVT",
        "codigo": 25,
        "categoria": "Fixo"
    }
}
```

O `GET` deu tudo certo, mas quando tento fazer com o `POST` ele da esse erro, já fiquei algumas horas procurando e não encontro uma forma de solucionar meu problema.
Entra direto na opção de erro do POST.

Comment: Que eu saiba, o Angular não precisa de `var data = JSON.stringify(contato);`. O Angular por padrão já faz isso (e com o header application/json)

Comment: fiz isso para tentar resolver o problema, mas mesmo sem isso não funciona

Answer (score 0):

@EduardoBobato não tenho certeza do que vou te dizer agora pois nunca vi isso em lugar nenhum e a resposta é da minha cabeça mas acho que voce nao pode dar um post para um arquivo .json, visto que json não é uma linguagem de programaçao provavelmente não tem suporte para variaveis tipo post.

Se seu servidor suportar php tente mudar o arquivo contatos.json para contatos.php e coloque no seu interior o codigo:

```
<?php
print_r(
  json_encode(
    [
        "nome"=> "Larissa",
        "telefone"=> "9999-3399",
        "cor"=> "orange",
        "data"=> "2015-04-12T12:53:46.204Z",
        "operadora"=> [
            "nome"=> "GVT",
            "codigo"=> 25,
            "categoria"=> "Fixo"
        ]
    ]
  )
);
```